# $2a+5b=n$ - recurrence of the sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Find a recurrence for the sequence $u_n=$ number of nonnegative
>   integral solutions of $$2a+5b=n.$$

I think I can use a generating function, but I'm a bit confused at this point. Is anyone is able to give me a hint? I would like to solve the problem myself, so of emblem, I would ask you not to solve the problem.

Comment: Typically, you'd write $u_n=u_{n-5}+u_{n-2}$ but that over-counts. Can you subtract something to get the right total?

Comment: Could you explain to me in detail why is this true? I try to do it by myself since yesterday, and I am not able to solve it.

Comment: I didn't say that was true, I said it was a first effort. You need to subtract something from that recurrence, because that recurrence over-counts.

Comment: Integer solutions to $2a+5b=n$ may be related to integer solutions to $2(a−1)+5b=n−2$ and to $2a+5(b−1)=n−5$ and I might expect the recurrence to involve $u_{n−2}$ and $u_{n−5}$, and possibly $u_{n−7}$. This is what I know until now.  Are you able to help me more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generating function approach is:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_nx^n &= \left(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots\right)\left(1+x^5+x^{10}+\cdots\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{1-x^2}\frac{1}{1-x^5}
\end{align}$$

So:

$$\left(1-x^2-x^5+x^{7}\right) \sum_{n=0}^\infty u_nx^n = 1$$

Figuring out the coefficient of $x^m$ on the left side will give you a recurrence.

Comment: Ok, you use the Taylor serie for $\frac{1}{1-t}$. Good job!

Comment: I found $u_n = u_{n-2} + u_{n-5} - u_{n-7}$. Is it good as answer?

Comment: @george Yes. Note, this has a simple explanation: We count solutions for $n-2$ and add a $2$, then count solutions for $n-5$ and add a five. But we've counted twice solutions that have at least one $5$ or $2$, so we have to subtract those, which is the number of solutions for $n-7$.